# Why does this recursive function output an array of x, n number of times?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Why does this recursive function work?

```js
let arr = []

function rep(x, n) {
  if (Math.sign(x) === -1) {
    return []
  }

  if (x < 1) {
    return 1
  } else {
    rep(x - 1, n)
  }
  arr.push(n)
  return arr
}

console.log(rep(5, 5))
```

I'm learning JS and about recursive functions. I made the above function to output an array of x, n number of times in an array. E.g. rep(2,5) would output [5,5], rep (3,3) would output [3,3,3] etc. But I don't fully understand why it works.

Am I right in thinking that the last thing the function does is return the completed array? If so, why does it not return [] or 1 when x goes to -1? I think I'm confusing myself but I'd appreciate an clear explanation. Thanks

I created the above function and was not expecting it work. So, I made it but I don't fully understand why it works.

Comment: A tip: [Browsers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/) and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started) have debugging capabilities that lets you "step through" your code, see where it's going, and what the values of variables are.

Comment: you only return from `rep` and if you look at this line `rep(x - 1, n)`, you are never actually doing anything with the return, so recursed `rep` function returns and then goes down to push another `n` onto the array.

Answer (score 1):

> If so, why does it not return [] or 1 when x goes to -1?

It does. But think about *where* it returns that to and what that bit of code does with it next.

You only ever log `console.log(rep(5, 5))`.

You don't log the response at any point where `x` is `-1`.

You would probably benefit from [stepping through the code with a debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/#event-breakpoint).

Comment: thanks for your reply. Perhaps I should have explained what I don't understand more clearly. I understand why [] or 1 isn't returned. What I don't understand is why the function doesn't return [5], [5,5], [5,5,5], [5,5,5,5], before finally returning [5,5,5,5,5]? It reaches the push bit just before return arr, so why not keep going?

Comment: ". What I don't understand is why the function doesn't return [5], [5,5], [5,5,5], [5,5,5,5]" — Again: **It does**. You just aren't logging those return values.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `rep(5,5)`, it gets called recursively as below:

```
rep(5,5)
    rep(4,5)
        rep(3,5)
            rep(2,5)
                rep(1,5)
```

When x = 1, the below condition is satisfied and causes the recursion to stop. So,

```
  if (x < 1) {
    return 1
  }
```

So, the below code does not get executed as `Math.sign(x)` never equal to -1

```
if (Math.sign(x) === -1) {
    return []
}
```

However, if you run call `rep(-3, 5)`, the above condition is satisfied and you will get `[]` as the output.